# Error:Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, powerbi-custom-visuals

**I want to create a Custom Visual on powerbi but get error after I run `pbiviz package` command on cmd.**

(I followed the guide on https://radacad.com/interactive-map-using-r-and-power-bi-create-custom-visual-part-1)

**Related Package Version:**

karma-webpack@3.0.5

karma@4.1.0

extract-text-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.0

Note:"npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@next" can't work with me

**Error message:**

> info   Building visual...
>
> info   Start preparing plugin template
>
> (node:868) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new
>   API on `.hooks` instead
>
> info   Finish preparing plugin template
>
> info   Start packaging...
>
> error  Author name is not specified
>
> error  Author e-mail is not specified
>
> error  The visual description is not specified
>
> error  supportUrl is not specified

Comment: What is your webpack version ?

Comment: @TonyNgo webpack@4.32.2

Comment: It's just a normal warning since they still use old API. I have same issue but will not affect to your code

Comment: @TonyNgo My Powershell doesn't run after returning "Compiled successfully.". I don't know if this is normal

Comment: Ok can you upload your webpack config file for me to see

Comment: @TonyNgo Anyway, I was able to develop custom visual normally. Can I ask you another question about formatting the custom visual?

Comment: Sure What is your question ? But I think is way of topic of your current question

Comment: @TonyNgo Thanks Tony. I'm going to develop a custom visual with R so that it can be displayed properly in PowerBI. I made a bar chart. Now one of the problems is that I don't know where to set the size of the image. The image in my custom visual is so large in powerbi that even a full-screen display can only see a part of the image. I hope the image can be displayed completely.（More directly, I hope the size of the image to be dynamic, it will become smaller as the custom visual become smaller）

Comment: Output seems OK, you need to specify name and email in pbiviz.json. After that tools starts to create *.pbiviz file in dist folder